# Container complains of port 443 after changing to 8443

Tags: ddev

When I run ddev start, I get the following error in the command line:

```
Failed to start amdocs-stage: Unable to listen on required ports, port 443 is already in use,
Troubleshooting suggestions at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/troubleshooting/#unable-listen
```

I went to my configuration file, replaced port 443 for 8443, and port 80 for 8000. However after I run ddev restart, I still see the same error. All instructed [here](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/troubleshooting/#unable-listen)

I don't have lando, and stopped all the services running through brew.

My Docker desktop is running, and the config.yaml inside .ddev looks like this:

```
name: cohesion-test
type: drupal8
docroot: web
php_version: "7.4"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "8000"
router_https_port: "8443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
mariadb_version: "10.3"
mysql_version: ""
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: ""
web_environment: []
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using docker-container? Which images? Where is the config?

Comment: @akop ddev runs on top of docker, and docker is currently active. I  edited the question and shared the config.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have more than one project active (or perhaps "paused") and the other projects still use port 443 (`router_https_port` is not a global setting). Do a `ddev poweroff` to stop all projects and then `ddev start`. If that doesn't do it, remove any additional containers that ddev may not know about with `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`.

You also may want to look at https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2981, which explains that there is a bug in current Docker Desktop for Mac v3.3.3, which regularly creates problems with port access that require `ddev poweroff` and a docker restart.

Comment: Added to this the current docker desktop bug "You also may want to look at https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2981, which explains that there is a bug in current Docker Desktop for Mac v3.3.3, which regularly creates problems with port access that require `ddev poweroff` and a docker restart."